# Is there a x64 bit version of Enterprise Library 5?

Tags: 64-bit, enterprise-library

I am converting some 32-bit .Net apps to x64.  Enterprise Library 5 (32-bit) is used in a bunch of our apps, so I am under the impression that when we re-compile those in x64, then we will need to pull in a x64 version of EntLib.  Does anyone know if that exists?  I keep searching and I can't seem to find a straight answer - I find burbs about x64 configuration manager tool, but no info about a installable 64-bit version of EntLib5.

Comment: you can just keep using the 32bit version if you like, it works fine with 64bit

Comment: I concur, I've never done anything special

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses Gents.  However, I am still confused...if I change my apps into x64 apps, then wont they fail in calling the 32 bit EntLib assemblies in process?  (i.e. x64 can't call x86)

Comment: x64 can call x86. It's the other way round that doesn't work.

Comment: @paul no if he compiles his .NET assembly targeting x64 then it will not be able to load assemblies targeted at x86.  64-bit code can not load 32-bit code and vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

The entlib assemblies are architecture neutral. They can be loaded by either 32 or 64 bit processes with no changes.

On a 32-bit process, they'll run as 32-bit. On a 64-bit process, they'll run as 64 bits. No changes needed.

Remember, they're IL, not native code, and don't call into anything native, so there's no bitness dependencies.